# Porque o servidor local não inicia com npm run dev

Tags: node.js, react

Estou tendo um problema com a inicialização de aplicação React, tanto uma aplicação nova quanto uma aplicação clonada quando rodo `npm run dev` não aparece o link `http://localhost:5173` e fica como na imagem, este comportamento acontece em 3 computadores meus, 2 windows 10 e 1 windows 11.
[Isto é o que acontece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk2xE.png)

Já troquei versão do Vite, atualizei Node e sempre com o mesmo comportamento. Alguém tem idéia do que pode causar isso?

Answer (score -3):

O comando `npm run dev` irar buscar no arquivo package.json um código chamado dev então você tem colocar o seguinte trecho no arquivo
`"dev" : "insira o código a ser executado aqui",` .

sobre não aparecer o link no console, você deve colocar a mão. por exemplo no express seria assim.

```
app.listen(8080, ()=>{
   console.log('http://localhost:8080')
})
```